# Couldnot store huge text content contains texts,numbers in mysql table (datatype-TEXT)

Tags: mysql, type-conversion

Im having `TEXT` datatype field in mysql table.I need to store large text content in that field which contains texts, numbers..etc. But when i try to insert it, It never insert the large text content which has various characters.
Then i couldnot use the `VARCHAR` datatype for largecontent..What to do?

Comment: What do you mean by _... It never insert the large text content ..._? How are you reading from source and trying to set values for the destination fields?

Comment: Also read: [_**Data Types Storage Requirements for Strings**_](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/storage-requirements.html#data-types-storage-reqs-strings)

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-type-overview.html#idm139828689342000